# Swift 4: URLSession отменить Redirect

Tags: swift, rest

при моём запросе в случае удачи сервер должен ответить с StatusCode 302 (Redirect). Swift автоматически выполняет переход и выдает 200.  как отключить авто переход по ссылке redirect?

```
let params = ["username":LoginField.text, "password":PassField.text] as! Dictionary<String, String>

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: NSLocalizedString("url_login", comment: ""))!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 302 {

                result=1;

            }else{
                result=0;
            }
        }
        semaphore.signal() 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно установить делегат ([URLSessionTaskDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate)) для вашей сесии `URLSession` и в делегате реализовать метод

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, 
        willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, 
                         newRequest request: URLRequest, 
                          completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {}
```

в котором `response` и будет нужный вам объект до редиректа. 
[ссылка на метод](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1411626-urlsession) и [Apple гайд](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/RequestChanges.html) по работе с редиректами и другими изменениями сессии (Handling Redirects and Other Request Changes)